# Are there cases where constexpr should be avoided, even it it could be used?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

If an object is declared `const`, its value is guaranteed to be available only at runtime, but if it's declared `constexpr`, the value is guaranteed to be available both during compilation and at runtime. So if I have an object whose value is available during compilation, are there any situations where I should not declare it `constexpr`?

```
const int magicValue = 42;      // Does this ever make sense
                                // (using const instead of constexpr)?
```

For functions, if a function can return a value computed during compilation when passed arguments with values available during compilation, would it ever make sense to not declare the function `constexpr`?

```
struct Point { int x; int y; };

Point midPoint(Point p1, Point p2)                       // Does this ever make
{                                                        // sense (not declaring
    return { (p1.x + p2.x) / 2 , (p1.y + p2.y) / 2 };    // the function
}                                                        // constexpr)?
```

The only case I can conceive of is when you don't want to commit to the function being able to compute a compile-time constant when called with known-at-compile-time arguments, e.g., if you want to preserve the flexibility to change `midPoint`'s implementation without changing its interface (thus potentially breaking callers). For example, you might want to preserve the flexibility to add non-`constexpr` side-effects to `midPoint`, e.g., IO.

Comment: In code that has to compile under previous iterations of the standard? For example, library code that you want to be able to compile with a C++03 compiler.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm really interested in cases where it would compile either way.

Comment: @stefan Why can you not benchmark a `constexpr` function? If the arguments are supplied at run-time, it will be computed at run-time. If the arguments are known at compile-time, even a non-`constexpr` function might be computed at compile-time. It's nothing to do with whether the function is marked as `constexpr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For variables, I don't see any reason not to use `constexpr` when  you can. But it's not always possible to do so, e.g. when the initializer of a variable is computed by a virtual function e.g.

Adding `constexpr` to a function is an **interface change**: you are expressing the fact that you can use it to initialize `constexpr` variables. This imposes constraints on the implementation of your function, such as no calling of virtual functions, no dynamic memory allocations and no lambda functions as function objects.

Note that the resolution to [**LWG issue 2013**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2013) does not allow implementers of the Standard Library the freedom to add `constexpr` to library functions. One of the reasons is that declaring a function `constexpr` can inhibit certain debugging implementations that do dynamic allocations (notably iterator checking). This means that future expansions of `constexpr` to the Standard Library need to be separate proposals. This is in contrast to `noexcept`, where library writers have more freedom.

Comment: `Adding constexpr to a function is an interface change`: Thank you for this helpful note.  Is there an official list of what counts as interface changes?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* change a const:

```
int const x = 1;

*const_cast<int *>(&x) = 5;
```

You cannot do the same with constexpr, which allows the compiler to *know* without a doubt that the expression is available at compile time, and thus optimizations are possible.

Comment: Well if you don't mind the nasal demons... Modifying an object declared as `const` invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Actually, modifying an object *defined* as `const` invokes UB. (It's not enough for it to be merely *declared* `const`.)