# Should all comparison operators be constexpr for a potentially constexpr object

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Consider the following struct with a single data member and an `operator==`

```
struct S {
    int a_;
    /*constexpr*/ bool operator==(const S& other) const {
        return a_ == other.a_;
    }
};
```

in its use, two structs can easily be created as `constexpr` with an initialization list

```
int main() {
    constexpr S s1 = {1};
    constexpr S s2 = {2};
    constexpr bool b = s1 == s2; // error
}
```

the bool comparison can't compile because the `==` operator is not marked as `constexpr`,  When it is, the program compiles.

Should all comparison operators for any class that can be `constexpr` also be marked as `constexpr`?  I don't see any reason why not, but I also haven't seen code practicing this.

I would also take it a step further and ask if something like `operator*(S, S)` should be `constexpr` as well, all the time.

Comment: `constexpr` in C++11 imposes tight constraints on the implementation of a function. See the related http://stackoverflow.com/a/20970745/420683 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5116399/420683 Imagine a string comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20901977/420683

Comment: @dyp constexpr rules are relaxed in C++1y and allow all the loop construct, a constexpr string equality function will looks like an usual non constexpr one in a near future.

Comment: If you want those functions to be usable in a constant expression, they must be `constexpr`. If you don't need them usable in a constant expression, it doesn't matter. This is an interface issue just like marking member functions `const` - you should define the interface to support the intended usage.

Comment: @galop1n See my comment to the question at the third link ;) but for C++11 and to a lesser degree in C++1y, performance might still be an issue. I consider the interface issue more important (e.g. you can't declare it non-constexpr in debug but constexpr in release if someone needs to rely on the constexpr-ness).

Answer (score 1):

The Thing is that comparison is not always the type that the user could use standard comparison operators.Sometimes two objects can be compared and `greater than` or `less Than` or `equals to` can have new definitions .For example in a class that holds objects of type Coordinates Comparison can be defined in a custom way. For example :

```
Coordinate c1(3,5)
Coordinate c2(4,2)
```

We can overload the `==` operator to return True for `c1==c2` whenever `c1.x == c2.x` or `c1.y==c2.y` or when both expressions are true.

The same goes for `constexpr` type objects and structs

Answer (score 0):

> Should all comparison operators for any class that can be constexpr also be marked as constexpr?
>
> I would also take it a step further and ask if something like operator*(S, S) should be constexpr as well, all the time.

Surely they should, if you want to write nicely usable code.

> I don't see any reason why not, but I also haven't seen code practicing this.

To see a good example, take a look at std::pair and std::tuple implementations. However, usually you won't write classes that will be useful as compile-time values.

Comment: *"To see a good example, take a look at std::pair and std::tuple implementations."* Member functions of class templates marked as `constexpr` are *optionally* `constexpr`. I.e. if and only if their function bodies fulfil the `constexpr` requirements, they're *actually* `constexpr`. This is not the case for member functions of ordinary (non-template) classes. See [dcl.constexpr]/6

Comment: @dyp: I understand it, but how is it related to the examples I've given?

Comment: Well `std::tuple` and `std::pair` are class templates...? And they're particularly simple classes, as they're basically just aggregates. There are classes where you *can't* make the comparison operator `constexpr`, e.g. if they need to use a `dynamic_cast`, or where a checked (debug) implementation cannot be `constexpr`.

Comment: @dyp: yes. it sounds reasonable, thank you. But in cases when the template parameters' methods and operators are constexpr, the corresponding std::tuple's and std::pair's methods/operators will also be constexpr, won't they?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with *optional*. Probably that's the wrong term, something like *if possible* is more appropriate. For example, `std::pair<X,Y>::operator==` is `constexpr` IFF `X::operator==` and `Y::operator==` are `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

> The constexpr specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time. Such variables and functions can then be used where only compile time constant expressions are allowed.

as stated, if your operator may be used as compile time constant, declare it as constexpr. Otherwise, just save some typing, keep a clean view of code and don't confuse others.